# Silverlight 3 version compatibility

Tags: silverlight

We've noticed a compatibility issue with a Silverlight 3 app which runs fine with v3.0.40818, v3.0.50106 and v4.0.50401 but refuses to load in v3.0.40624. Instead it gives a message box saying a more recent version of Silverlight is required.

Does anyone know what the changes were between 3.0.40624 and 3.0.40818 or why the app might not be compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find that 3.0.40624 is a Beta version of Silverlight 3.  You should recommend to any users you have that still have this Beta version to upgrade.

Comment: That's what I thought, but wasn't able to find conclusive evidence. Cheers